# Rails 3 new_record? deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails 3 app and I am planning to use the ActiveRecord method new_record? on my shared form to show the user either a Create or Update button. I looked at [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F) and for this method and it says

> Method Deprecated: This method is
>   deprecated on the latest stable
>   version of Rails. The last existing
>   version (v2.3.8) is shown here.

What exactly does that mean? Does it mean that it will no longer be available moving forward?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ActiveRecord::Persistence makes no mention of deprecation... I believe APIDock is simply fooled by the restructuring of the classes.  If the method were deprecated, rails would generate a warning when it was used.

see: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F